Mypy type complaint not tracking if-branch logic. How should I fix?
I have the following code:
array: list[list[str | None]] = []
# ...
item_text: str = ""
if array[0][col] is not None:
    item_text = array[0][col]

In VSCode, mypy throws the following complaint
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str | None", variable has type "str")

(see attached figure). The if branch conditioning the type of array[0][col] does not seem to be registered by mypy. Can I remedy this?


This is a very common question. Mypy cannot be sure that the two accesses will return the same value; store the value in a variable and operate on that instead: if (v := array[0][col]) is not None: item_text = v. There should be a good dupe somewhere.

This question is similar to: Mypy doesn't consider the if condition. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
